# Which method is faster to select body element?

Tags: javascript, performance

What is better to use for performance in JavaScript?

```
document.children[0].children[1]
```

vs

```
document.querySelector('body')
```

Which is more faster in performance?

Comment: I'd say `document.body`, but it really doesn't matter, you'll never notice the difference

Answer (score 35):

Here you've the result from fast to slow:

1. `document.body` (by far)
2. `document.querySelector('body')`,  `document.children[0].children[1]`, `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]` (about the same)
3. `document.querySelectorAll("body")[0]`, `$('body')`

Source [JSBench](https://jsbench.me/mmkk5eakt9/1) (try it yourself)

Comment: And what about the JQuery notation `$('body')` is this fast or not?

Comment: @Luïs almost as slow as `querySelectorAll` (I updated the test)